# How to remove duplicates from a sharepoint view?

Tags: list, list-view

I have a sharepoint views containing different items but according to the columns displayed in my view, those items are the same:

```
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
A B C E
```

That I would like to display like:

```
A B C D
A B C E
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Isn't there a `DISTINCT` or `UNIQUE` option?

Comment: agree with @moontear , the only way to do is grouping in view. SharePoint does not supports "DISTINCT" or "UNIQUE".

Comment: There is a unique attribute for a field in a list, but it requires you set up the field that way during creation. It is not for "after the fact", so will have no bearing here. This approach does not limit the view, but limits duplicates during insertion of the data in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by fields in a view. To do that you can just modify the view and group by e.g. "Column A".